# transpose many columns in many rows with the same info (week)

Tags: excel

Please help with the below situation. In left is the data base and in right the result of the function. 
[image]

Comment: I am not quite sure but, pivot table might help you achieve it

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula as in the image below,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH($A9,$A:$A,0)&":I"&MATCH($A9,$A:$A,0)),0,MATCH(B$8,INDIRECT("A"&MATCH($A9,$A:$A,0)&":I"&MATCH($A9,$A:$A,0)),0)-1),"")
```

[image]